# Modx Gallery Error

Tags: php, gallery, modx, portfolio

I have a portfolio page with small boxes with a image and link.
This seems (after struggling in code) to work, but the image don't work.

For each porject on the portfolio page:

```
[[!Gallery? &album=`[[+tv.gallery]]` &limit=`1` &thumbWidth=`870` &thumbHeight=`400` &thumbZoomCrop=`2` &toPlaceholder=`projecten`]]

<li class="[[dynamicWidget]]" id="[[+tv.category]]">
[[!+projecten:notempty=`
<div class="item">
  <a href="[[~[[+id]]]]" title="[[+description]]">
    <img src="[[+projecten.image]]" alt="[[+description]]" />
  </a>
</div>
`]]
</li>
```

( i'm using the default gallery function)
thetv.gallery is the id of the gallery wich i like to use, but now i takes only the first album, not the first picture of a project.

It works, but only the selected image is not the album's first item (tv.gallery) but the first or second image in that album.

So:
- i have 2 pages with each a gallery witht to images
- the code gives me the first album with picture 1 and picture 2.

How to solve this, please give me some advice because i really want this script to be finished. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood exactly what you want to do, but maybe you should be using the [GalleryAlbums](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/Gallery.GalleryAlbums) snippet in this case, in combination with the `albumCoverSort` option.

**edit:** based on your comment, it looks like [Gallery](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/Gallery.Gallery) might be the best choice:

```
[[!Gallery? &album=`myProject` &limit=`1` &sort=`rank`]]
```

Refer to the docs for more info about how to sort the thumbnail shown.

Comment: I want for all my projects, with have a gallery with mulitple images per project a thumbnail on the project page..

Comment: Edited my code to the latest version, works fine but the image location is not right, i need the album i put in tv.gallery (vallue as int, album 1 = 1, album2 = 2...)

Comment: So it works, it shows a image. but it takes everythime the first album (and for project one image1, project 2 image 2)

See the source code ow www.roywagemakers.nl/webdesign/ for a example.

Comment: It's really difficult to guess without seeing how your templates and Gallery albums are set up. What have you tried?